# Convex Hull of discrete points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

If i was to give an $n \times n$ grid with each grid point having probability $p$ of being selected, would it be difficult to calculate distributions of various measures regarding the convex hull of all selected points? I.e the distribution of the number of extreme points or total area covered (assuming this is defined appropriately). I've seen a lot of stuff on convex hulls in a continuous setting but not much in a discrete setting, if anyone could mention any interesting things they may know, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which $p$ you choose! Your question is regarding what is called site percolation on the grid, and this is a huge field of research. There is a critical value of $p$, called $p_c$, where there is a phase transition.

If you consider the total number of vertices, then it is always going to be roughly $pn^2$. Taking convex hulls cannot increase it much since long tentacles can only be at most logarithmic in size which can create a significant difference.

The largest cluster for $p<p_c$ is $\log n$ in size. For $p>p_c$, the largest cluster is roughly $n^2$ in size and when properly rescaled converges to a convex shape, which is a recent result, see

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.0745v1.pdf

At p=p_c, the largest cluster is $n^\gamma$ for some $0<\gamma<1$ and is much harder to handle.

If you want to know what is $p_c$, then the answer is much simpler if you choose every edge randomly rather than grid points (equivalently do bond percolation.) In this case $p_c =1/2$.